# How to write xpath for Select name class for the below scenario in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, xpath, web-applications

[image]

Hello,

I'm trying to choose a card from the card list(as shown in the below screenshot) and the locator for the same is highlighted in the "Elements" section. This is a Select name class and the below xpath didn't work for me. Could you please help me if there is other way to write the xpath?

//select[@class='co-dropdown__select co-payment-card__select']//option[2]

Comment: You need post the relevant Html not the screenshot.Its difficult for other contributor to post an answer based on opinion.Hope you understand what I mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try below css selector**

```
 Select select= new Select(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("select.co-dropdown_select.co-payment-card__select")));    
 select.selectByIndex(index);
```

Comment: Thanks for ur response. i'm just looking for xpath in javascript :)

Comment: What about `//*[name()="select" and starts-with(@class,"co-dropdown")]//option[2]` ?

Answer (score 1):

try using this:

```
WebElement dropDownList = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".co-dropdown__select.co-payment-card__select")); 
Select card= new Select(dropDownList);
card.selectByIndex(2);
```

Comment: Appreciate your response :)

Comment: Please upvote if it helped you so that it could help others.